# Creating a histogram with the number of occurrences at multiple places

Tags: r, histogram

I have a set of data that looks like that (just way bigger):

```
2  7
3  9
5  3
2  4
7  3
3  4   
2  2
```

and I would like to produce a histogram with bars at 2 of height (7+4+2), so 13, at 3 of height 13, 5 at 3 and 7 at 3.

I hope the question is not too dumb, but the tutorials I found did not discuss this problem. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: For 2, you're looking at the numbers next to 2. For 3, how do you then get 5 and 7? By looking before 3? There's another 7 and another 3. Even then, what's the rule to decide forward or backward look-up?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot I had to leave a line free. Edited the post above to make it understandable.

Comment: So you want to sum column 2 within values of column 1? Also, make a reproducible example that we can cut and paste.

Comment: No. The left column contains the data I want to count and the right column the number of appearances that were counted. So the first line means, the number 2 appeared 7 times. But not all occurences have to be in the same line. The 2 for example reappears in lines 4 (4 times) and 7 (2 times) for a total number of 13 times.

Comment: YES! You want to sum all the values in column 2 for each value of column 1? So where column 1 is equal to 2, you sum the values 7, 4, and 3. Where column 1 is equal to 7, you sum the value 3 from column 2 only. Where column 2 is equal to six you get zero.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood you. You are correct of course. Not to forget: After that I want to create a histogram of that ;)

Comment: You mean you want a barplot, right?

Comment: Yeah. The answers below seem good, I'm just downloading ggplot2 to try them out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DF <- read.table(text="2 7
3 9    
5 3    
2 4    
7 3    
3 4    
2 2")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF,aes(x=V1,y=V2)) +stat_summary(fun.y=sum,geom="bar")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the aggregated sums out of the data and plot them later (the ggplot solution does it all) then, starting from DF:

```
> aggregate(V2~V1,data=DF,sum)
  V1 V2
1  2 13
2  3 13
3  5  3
4  7  3
```

Answer (score 3):

Other answers given here probably already answer your question, but for the sake of completeness, if you do not wish to depend on the `ggplot` package (I cannot really think of a reason for this, but you might) you could use a combination of `aggregate` and `barplot`.

```
> ADF <- aggregate(DF$V2, by = list(V1=DF$V1), FUN = sum)
> barplot(ADF$x, names.arg=ADF$V1)
```